# Check an part of url exist in php

Tags: php

I have an URL:

```
http://abv.com/
```

How can I check if `/en/` is in the URL, for example:

```
 http://abv.com/en/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strpos()`.

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// The !== operator can also be used.  Using != would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' is 0. The statement (0 != false) evaluates 
// to false.
if ($pos !== false) {
     echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
         echo " and exists at position $pos";
} else {
     echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the URL and split it by slashes - use the `.explode()` function.

```
$url =  'http://abv.com/en/';
$urlParts = explode('/',$url);
array_shift($urlParts);
array_shift($urlParts);
```

Using `array_shift()` twice you remove the unwanted `http` and the blank item due to the double slash...

```
Array
(
    [0] => abv.com
    [1] => en
    [2] =>
)
```

---

[`.parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) also has some usefull features for dealing with URL strings.  You should check it out also.

```
$url =  'http://abv.com/en/';
$urlParts = parse_url($url);
$pathParts = explode('/',$urlParts['path']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
if (strpos($url, '/en/') !== false) {
    // found!
}
```

If you want to check just the path, though, using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) can be helpful:

```
if (strpos(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/en/') !== false) {
    // found in the path!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate url using php explode function, then check if url having "en" (country code ) or not.

```
$url = 'http://abv.com/en/';
          $expurl = explode('/', $url);
          print_r($expurl);            
          foreach ($expurl as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 'en') {
              # do what you want
            }
          }
```

Array result

```
  Array ( [0] => http: [1] => [2] => abv.com [3] => en [4] => )
```